# Can't get output from The Silver Searcher through Subprocess call

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to write a wrapper for [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) in Python (The Silver Searcher is like ack and grep).

However, I can't call the program sucesfully using the subprocess–library. I can get information like the help text or version, but can't launch a search (when I try, it fails and prints the help text).

I've tried the following in vain:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['ag', 'fit'], shell=True)
p.communicate()

p = subprocess.Popen(['ag', 'fit'])
p.communicate()

p = subprocess.Popen(['ag', 'fit'], shell=True)
p.wait()
p.communicate()

p = subprocess.Popen(['ag', 'fit'])
p.wait()
p.communicate()
```

How can I capture the output from The Silver Searcher? Preferebly as it's created (a call mey take several seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works on my system:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["ag", "fit"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.communicate()
```

Comment: All I get is `('', None)`.
Running Python 2.7.8 and ag 0.26.0.

Comment: I believe that's what you'll see if `ag` works correctly, but finds nothing. If running the command in the shell yields some matches, then maybe there is an issue with the current working directory? That is, maybe the cwd of your python script isn't what you think it is, and so the `ag` command isn't able to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Good idea, but not the problem :/ I tried using `grep` as well, which worked just fine. I checked that the programs returned the same line in my terminal (and checked the path with `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Installing `ag` with Homebrew instead of Macports seems to solve this.

Comment: I had to add a directory to the command for it to work for me through a notebook. `subprocess.Popen(["ag", "fit", "."], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Answer (score 1):

I used IPython and faced with the same issue. 
Versions:

- Python 2.7.12
- IPython 5.3.0
- ag 0.32.0

Resolved with option `--vimgrep` for `ag` call.

```
In [1]: file_list = ! ag one

In [2]: file_list
Out[2]: []

In [3]: file_list = ! ag one --vimgrep

In [4]: file_list
Out[4]: ['file2:1:1:one', 'file1:1:1:one', 'file3:1:1:one']

In [5]:
```

Comment: Nice… but this is an old question, so which version of Python and ag did you use?